# &Array() - Final Row prefixed with ampersand after Updating Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to update only some values of an Array directly. Which is working perfectly. I am using the following method:

```
foreach( $items as &$item ) {
    if( $criteria == 'correct' ) {
      // update array
      $item['update_me'] = 'updated';
    }
}
```

So I now have an updated array called $items.

However, the problem I have, is when this Array is output to screen (via another foreach loop), the last row of the Array is missing.

If I print the entire array via the var_dump( $items ); method, I noticed that each row is prefixed with Array(9). Yet the last row is prefixed with &Array(9) - notice the leading ampersand. I'm sure this is significant! But I'm unsure what it means. Why is it only applied to the final row in the Array? And how do I get rid of it?

**From comment:**

```
array(6) { 
    [0]=> array(9) { 
        ["item_id"]=> string(4) "1" 
        ["item_description"]=> string(9) "blah blah" 
        ["quantity"]=> string(1) "4" 
        ["unit_cost"]=> string(4) "5.00" 
        ["subtotal"]=> string(4) "20.00" 
    } 
    [1]=> &array(9) { 
        ["item_id"]=> string(4) "2" 
        ["item_description"]=> string(9) "blah blah" 
        ["quantity"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["unit_cost"]=> string(4) "5.99" 
        ["subtotal"]=> string(4) "5.99" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Show us all of the relevant code. Show us the relevant output. Tell us what language you are using.

Comment: Should hopefully be fixed now. But here is the output in case anyone is interested for reference:`array(6) 
{ [0]=> array(9) 
 { ["item_id"]=> string(4) "1" 
   ["item_description"]=> string(9) "blah blah" 
   ["quantity"]=> string(1) "4" 
   ["unit_cost"]=> string(4) "5.00" 
   ["subtotal"]=> string(4) "20.00" 
 } 
  [1]=> &array(9) 
 { ["item_id"]=> string(4) "2" 
   ["item_description"]=> string(9) "blah blah" 
    ["quantity"]=> string(1) "1" 
   ["unit_cost"]=> string(4) "5.99" 
   ["subtotal"]=> string(4) "5.99" 
 } 
} `

Comment: And it is in PHP, sorry! Should have noted that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that's not the nicest way to do this. i'd suggest doing it this way:

```
foreach( array_keys($items) as $itemkey ) {
    if( $criteria == 'correct' ) {
        // update array
        $items[$itemkey]['update_me'] = 'updated';
    }
}
```

Comment: That appears to work a lot better! Will need to do a bit of testing just to make sure it's holding up, but so far so good. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

You must unset $item after loop. Correct code:

```
foreach( $items as &$item ) {
    if( $criteria == 'correct' ) {
      // update array
      $item['update_me'] = 'updated';
    }
}
unset($item);
```

& sign in the var_dump result specify that this is reference. You can check it by using xdebug_zval_dump() function:

```
xdebug_zval_dump($item)
```

You'll see that is_ref=true. In PHP this means that there are another variables pointing to the same zval container (what is zval? see here http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php).
If you're using & in loop you must always unset reference after the loop to avoid hard-to-detect errors.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if it is the case here, but by-reference foreach loops are known to cause these kind of problems if the reference is not unset after the loop (there's a warning about it [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)). Try adding `unset($item);` right after the update foreach finishes and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: That's interesting. The solution below seems to have worked, but I may try this too out of curiosity.